# SSRS 2019 - Report Builder TLS 1.2 error

Tags: ssl, ssrs

I have 2 SSRS 2019 servers, and I'm using Report Builder 15 to connect to SSAS over an OLAP https connection.  The connection works fine and I'll able to successfully build a report and get results using the Query Designer tool in Report Builder.  My issue only occurs when I go to run the report in Report Builder (see errors below).  I have TLS 1.2 enforced using the IISCrypto tool and the registry settings to enable TLS 1.2 for .Net are also in place.

### An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

### Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

### The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

The connection either timed out or was lost.

Comment: I should just add that the connection works fine from Excel as well, and I'm able to run the report in Report Builder when I use a non-https address.  The error only occurs when the address is https.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue so just wanted to post it in case anyone comes across this. But a quick recap of my config: SSRS is setup with a data source which is configured as SSAS and points to a public facing OLAP over http URL. This worked fine for creating reports but running returned an error. I noticed after doing packet capture that the SSRS server seemed to be trying to connect to that OLAP address (which was local to the SSRS server but the public address was not accessible), so I set a hosts file entry of the public URL to 127.0.0.1 and now the reports run successfully.